# Atlas failing in Boston Dynamics Controller demo

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Following instructions for the [Boston Dynamics Controller Demo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/Boston_Dynamics_Controller_Demo) I always end up with the robot failing after trying to perform the first step.

I've uploaded a video to show the problem:  http://youtu.be/ACivMqVeA4U

I'm using latest stable 64bits packages: gazebo 1.6.1-2~precise and drcsim 2.3.0-3~precise. I've detected that my real time factor is lower than tutorial pictures: 0.22 just after launch the simulator and robot.

Computer is an AMD FX-8150 Eight-Core, 32Gb RAM and Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTX. Useful output from launch could be:

> Error [Events.hh:141] Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart is deprecated in v 1.5.0. Please use Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin
>
> [ INFO] [1365426395.253649823]: Loading MultiSense ROS node.
>
> [ INFO] [1365426395.329325360, 0.017820000]: AtlasPlugin default controller statistics 1kHz
>
> [  0.058451    0.021096    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.058451    0.021096    0.000000    ]
>
> [  1.004841   -0.506295    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.121695   -0.036243    0.000000    ]
>
> [  1.352409   -0.689738    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.065160   -0.017450    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.716787   -0.348561    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.056265   -0.008449    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.958749   -0.300143    0.000000    ]
>
> [  0.055046   -0.013692    0.000000    ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2274/atlas-failing-in-boston-dynamics-controller-demo/) by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1485 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

confirmed broken, need [this patch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/183/bdi-expects-body1force-and-body1torque/diff)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-04-09**:
I can confirm that current drcsim_2.3 branch fix the error. Thanks John.